# Image Data triggers not working

Tags: wpf, datatrigger

I have bindings for images in listviews that work fine with boolean conditions. I have created a custom property PlotSettingsFileExists, and an image on a usercontrol but nothing seems to show at runtime.

```
public partial class BatchDialogUC : UserControl
    {
    public bool PlotSettingsFileExists
        {
        get { return File.Exists(Strada.Settings.PlotTemplateFile); }
        }
    }

<Image Name="imgPltSettings" Width="16" Height="16">
            <Image.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Image">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PlotSettingsFileExists}" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="/StradaRPC;component/Resources/imgDrawing.png"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PlotSettingsFileExists}" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="/StradaRPC;component/Resources/ExlamationMark.png"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on this?

Comment: And what is the value of Strada.Settings.PlotTemplateFile pertinent to your test?

Comment: Did you set the DataContext for the binding?

Comment: Are you seeing any binding errors in the output window?

Comment: @AlexBell The Strada,Settings.PlotTemplateFile returns a path.

Comment: I'll take a look at the DataContext @Karmacon

Comment: Is this a valid path?

Comment: It is a valid path - however, if it wasn't, it would return false

Comment: just set the DataContext.                                                                             public BatchDialogUC()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

Comment: Thanks @RamNivas that worked a treat!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks you have **PlotSettingsFileExists** property inside your view, but it should be defined in viewmodel and set viewmodel as datacontext of your usecontrol

Answer (score 0):

just set the DataContext. public BatchDialogUC() { InitializeComponent(); DataContext = this; } – Ram Nivas